# PHP calendar click function

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a calendar in PHP, I'm new in php btw. 
I would like to ask how I can add clicks in the days of the calendar, and when clicked open a window of events of the day that was clicked. and show the date and some content coming from mysql

i got the calendar from: http://www.webinfopedia.com/how-to-create-php-calendar.html

please help

EDIT

i'm trying do that way,
Sending code information:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventWindow(url) {
event_popupWin = window.open(url, 'event',  'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=400,height=400');
event_popupWin.opener = self;
}
</script>
```

and

```
   echo "<td valign=\"top\"><a href=\"java script:eventWindow('event.php?m=".$month."&d=".$dayArray["mday"]."&y=$year');\">".$dayArray["mday"]."</a><br/>";
```

no sucess!

Answer (score 0):

You would need JavaScript for that. PHP to fetch the data to display, but JavaScript to make it pop-up and probably also for AJAX to get the data.

I suggest you learn JavaScript/HTML. Remember that PHP is *server-sided* scripting. If it appears on the client's side, you can't use it (unless you need tasks done in your server, of course).

Comment: you can open a window\tab with out js (depending on definitions)

Comment: @Dagon JS/HTML/whatever but definitely not PHP.

Comment: Can you help me with code? 
I have no idea how to associate the script with php to open that window.
Please!